# Youtube Data API v3 drop in result count

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have used YouTube API v3 to retrieve the number of video searches as a function of location. The purpose of this data is to study the distribution of YouTube's public: urban/rural, center of the cities or the metropolitan area, etc.

As part of this study, I checked the stability of the public (if there are changes over time of public behavior), retrieving the information regularly over the last 3 months.

Around 3 weeks ago, I observed a sudden drop of the number of counts in total results. More specifically, I retrieve pageInfo.totalResults from search.list. Before the change, totalResults yielded up to tens of thousands in the cities and provided useful information about the rural areas. However, now the highest count gets to a few dozens in the same areas.

I have been using the exact same script to study these areas, yielding the same information with no change. All my searches through the API documentation obtained no result. There is no record of any change on the API or the way the results are stored/retrieved from the API.

Has there been any change on how pageInfo.totalResults is stored/retrieved? Or, is totalResults a accumulative variable, restoring the counts at a certain time of the year.

I will be happy to forward this issue to the correct place, but it seems the issue tracker of YouTube API is inactive currently.

Thanks and best regards,

Diego

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack cant comment on stealth changes made by Google try issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B

Comment: Hi, I have an open issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76456339

I have posted in stackoverflow again because I saw a lot more activity here. Could you please indicate any other contact channels that I could use? Thanks!